# Quicksort of Linked List in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, quicksort

Okay guys, after no success with gdb and valgrind, I humbly present my question to you. We were asked to implement a version of a quicksort in c, using the first element of the list as the pivot (to maintain comparability with a simple haskell implementation we did earlier in the semester). The LIST implementation was provided (make, print, and the structure definition), the rest is up to us. I am (surprise, surprise) receiving a segfault, but valgrind is turning up a HUGE number of errors as well as a stack overflow, so maybe some fresh eyes can help me.

My code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct CELL *LIST;
struct CELL {
    int element;
    LIST next;
};


LIST MakeList();
void PrintList(LIST);
LIST qSort(LIST);
int listLength(LIST);
LIST combine(LIST, LIST, LIST);


int main(){
   LIST list;
    printf ("enter a several numbers separated by spaces or returns and ended by Ctrl-D\n");
    list = MakeList();
    PrintList(qSort(list));
   return 0;
}

LIST qSort(LIST list){
   LIST current, pivot = list, temp = NULL;//use first element as pivot, start comparison at list->next
   LIST little, big, littleHead, bigHead;
   little = (LIST) malloc(sizeof(struct CELL));
   little->element = 0;
   little->next = NULL;
   littleHead = little;
   big = (LIST) malloc(sizeof(struct CELL));
   big->element = 0;
   big->next = NULL;
   bigHead = big;

   if(listLength(list) <= 1){//base case
      return list;
   }
//remove pivot by setting current to list->next
   current = list->next;

   do{
      if(current->element <= pivot->element){
         little->element = current->element;
         little->next = (LIST) malloc(sizeof(struct CELL));
         little = little->next;
         little->next = NULL;
      }
      else{
         big->element = current->element;
         big->next = (LIST) malloc(sizeof(struct CELL));
         big = big->next;
         big->next = NULL;
      }

      current = current->next;
   }while(current != NULL);

   littleHead = qSort(littleHead);
   bigHead = qSort(bigHead);

   return combine(littleHead, bigHead, pivot);
}

int listLength(LIST list){
   int length = 0;
   LIST current = list;
   if(NULL==list){
      return length;
   }
   else{
      while(current != NULL){
         current = current->next;
         length++;
      }
   }
   return length;
}



LIST combine(LIST little, LIST big, LIST pivot){
   LIST temp = little;
   while(temp->next != NULL){
      temp = temp->next;
   }
   temp->next = pivot;
   pivot->next = big;
   return little;
}

LIST MakeList()
{
    int x;
    LIST pNewCell;

    if (scanf("\%d", &x) == EOF) return NULL;
    else {
        pNewCell = (LIST) malloc(sizeof(struct CELL));
        pNewCell->next = MakeList();
        pNewCell->element = x;
        return pNewCell;
    }
}

void PrintList(LIST list)
{
    while (list != NULL) {
        printf("\%d\n", list->element);
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

And the valgrind output

```
==20391== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20391==    at 0x804855D: qSort (2100assignment4.c:45)
==20391==    by 0x80485E0: qSort (2100assignment4.c:61)
==20391==    by 0x80484BD: main (2100assignment4.c:22)
==20391==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==20391==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==20391==    by 0x8048574: qSort (2100assignment4.c:47)
==20391==    by 0x80484BD: main (2100assignment4.c:22)
==20391==
==20391== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20391==    at 0x804855D: qSort (2100assignment4.c:45)
==20391==    by 0x80485E0: qSort (2100assignment4.c:61)
==20391==    by 0x80485E0: qSort (2100assignment4.c:61)
==20391==    by 0x80484BD: main (2100assignment4.c:22)
==20391==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==20391==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==20391==    by 0x8048574: qSort (2100assignment4.c:47)
==20391==    by 0x80484BD: main (2100assignment4.c:22)
==20391==
==20391== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20391==    at 0x804855D: qSort (2100assignment4.c:45)
==20391==    by 0x80485E0: qSort (2100assignment4.c:61)
==20391==    by 0x80485E0: qSort (2100assignment4.c:61)
==20391==    by 0x80485E0: qSort (2100assignment4.c:61)
==20391==    by 0x80484BD: main (2100assignment4.c:22)
==20391==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==20391==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==20391==    by 0x8048574: qSort (2100assignment4.c:47)
==20391==    by 0x80485E0: qSort (2100assignment4.c:61)
==20391==    by 0x80484BD: main (2100assignment4.c:22)
==20391==
==20391== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xbe297ff4
==20391==
==20391== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==20391==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xBE297FF4
==20391==    at 0x402BE35: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==20391==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==20391==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==20391==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==20391==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==20391==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==20391== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xbe297fe4
==20391==
==20391== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==20391==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xBE297FE4
==20391==    at 0x4025430: _vgnU_freeres (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-x86-linux.so)
==20391==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==20391==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==20391==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==20391==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==20391==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==20391==
==20391== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20391==     in use at exit: 4,190,952 bytes in 523,869 blocks
==20391==   total heap usage: 523,869 allocs, 0 frees, 4,190,952 bytes allocated
==20391==
==20391== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20391==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20391==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20391==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20391==    still reachable: 4,190,952 bytes in 523,869 blocks
==20391==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20391== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20391==
==20391== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20391== ERROR SUMMARY: 261929 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems to start with:

```
if (scanf("\%d", &x) == EOF) return NULL;
```

The \ is not needed. It might be easier to check for != 1 as you are expecting one value.

This caused your MakeList to recurse infinitely (at least on my machine).

In your qsort function, your little and big lists always have a dummy entry at the end - done by this code

```
little->next = (LIST) malloc(sizeof(struct CELL));
little = little->next;
little->next = NULL;
```

This means that when you split your lists you always end up more entries than you started with, so it never finishes. Also note that these new entries don't have their element values set, which is probably where you are getting the uninitialized warnings.

You should rethink how you are storing the sub lists, perhaps start them as NULL, to indicate empty, although that will make adding new values a bit harder.

Comment: That scanf implementation was actually provided by the prof. It expects a Ctrl-D to end the list, which (to my understanding) on our unix machines simulates an EOF. It's kinda hokey, but he's a bit lazy I suppose. Thanks for your advice though, I will mess with my sublist storage and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your makelist function as below..

You will observe few changes.

> 1. `scanf` is correct by removing `\` (Refer The Dark's answer)
> 2. `scanf` read in while, this will ensure reading will stop if you enter any incompatible input like any letter instead of Ctrl + D.

```
LIST MakeList()
{
    int x;
    LIST pNewCell;

    while(scanf("%d", &x))
    {
        pNewCell = (LIST) malloc(sizeof(struct CELL));
        pNewCell->next = MakeList();
        pNewCell->element = x;
        return pNewCell;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```